# Integration of Power automation with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, power-automate

I want to integrate DocuSign with Power Automate. There are 2 things that needs to achieved in this integration

1. achieve completed documents to share point site ( which is completed )
2. if the flow fails due to any other factors, it should retrigger after 5sec, 10sec, 15 sec automatically.
3. And if the flow fails after these 3 attempts then it should mail the concerned team

Basically I designed a flow which is archiving Documents to a share point site. I am unable to add rest of the conditions.

My flow starts from When the envelope status changes -> Get envelope Documents -> Create a file in Sharepoint site (Try Block)

But I am unable to add a create a logic on 2nd and 3rd conditions .
I added delay and resubmit after last step (Create a file in sharepoint ) but the flow is continuously re-submitting after every failed attempt.

Answer (score 0):

See the [DocuSign Power Automate docs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gqy1619537336307&topicId=qno1619537607438.html&_LANG=enus).

Then ask more questions here when you have a specific question. Include information on what you already tried (what isn't working).

If you just want to store completed documents to a SharePoint site, first check out [DocuSign Agreement Actions](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=hzy1594673444380.html&_LANG=enus). There is an action which stores to SharePoint.

### Re: the flow is continuously re-submitting after every failed attempt

Sounds like you have a logic error in your flow. You can ***update*** (Edit) your question to include more information. Then we can better help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments . I already checked regarding Agreement action in DocuSign . There are certain limitations in that . For eg If the flow fails then DocuSign doesn't reflects the correct details. That's why I am switching to Power Automate. 

"See the DocuSign Power Automate docs.

Then ask more questions here when you have a specific question. Include information on what you already tried (what isn't working)."
Ans - Thats what I did ! Just see the comment , I mentioned the flow which I designed ... Just go down and see, I mentioned where I am facing the error .

Comment: Defiantly its a logic error and I am asking help for that logic only ..

Comment: If you don't provide the code, we can't be of help.